# Java read two text file at the same time

Tags: java, io, bufferedreader

I'm new to Java Programming. This one is really too long to read, but I'm just wondering if it's possible that reading two text file like this? cmp2.txt line is more than cmp1.txt line. Thanks in advance!

```
String input1 = "C:\\test\\compare\\cmp1.txt";
String input2 = "C:\\test\\compare\\cmp2.txt";

BufferedReader br1 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(input1));

BufferedReader br2 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(input2)); 

String line1;
String line2;

String index1;
String index2;

while ((line2 = br2.readLine()) != null) {
    line1 = br1.readLine();

    index1 = line1.split(",")[0];
    index2 = line2.split(",")[0];
    System.out.println(index1 + "\t" + index2);
```

cmp1 contains :

```
test1,1
test2,2
```

cmp2 contains :

```
test11,11
test14,14
test15,15
test9,9
```

script output :

```
test1   test11
test2   test14
```

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException at Test.main(Test.java:30)

expected output :

```
test1   test11
test2   test14
        test15
        test9
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because you are reading the first file as many times as there are lines in the second file, but you `null`-check on the result of reading the second file. You do not `null`-check `line1` before calling `split()` on it, which causes a `NullPointerException` when the second file has more lines than the first one.

You can fix this problem by adding a `null` check on `line1`, and replacing it with an empty `String` when it's `null`.

This would read both files to completion, no matter which one is longer:

```
while ((line2 = br2.readLine()) != null || (line1 = br1.readLine()) != null) {
    if (line1 == null) line1 = "";
    if (line2 == null) line2 = "";
    ... // Continue with the rest of the loop
}
```

Comment: variable line1 might not have been initialized

Comment: @tuturyokgaming That's because you did not add `= null` at the declaration. It should be `String line2=null`, not just `String line2`.

Comment: so this mean that my expected output is not possible?

Comment: @tuturyokgaming Why, of course it's possible. Did you change the declaration and recompiled?

Comment: Yes I changed the declaration and recompiled it, but the output is different.

Comment: @tuturyokgaming "different" is not descriptive enoug to understand what's going on. How many lines do you get? Does some of the lines look as you expect, or all lines are wrong? Do you get a crash at the end?

Comment: Ah yes, its fine now. I get it now @dasblinkenlight thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest

```
while ((line2 = br2.readLine()) != null &&
            (line1 = br1.readLine()) != null) {
```

That would read line by line in each file until either one of the files reaches EOF.

Comment: This one is right, but it's not printing out the data of line2 until reaches EOF